# Paypal IPN Valid in sandbox INVALID when live

Tags: php, mysql, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have been trying to implement the paypal IPN system into a clients site. Whenever I test this script in the IPN sandbox tool, it is validated and my actions are performed, however when I move it live, the IPN is returned as INVALID. 
I am at a wall here, thank you in advance for your help.
This is the IPN listener script:

```
<?php
/**
 *  PayPal IPN Listener
 *
 *  A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from 
 *  the PayPal server.
 *
 *  https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *
 *  @package    PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @author     Micah Carrick
 *  @copyright  (c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
 *  @version    2.0.5
 *  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
class IpnListener {

    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back 
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
     *  is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */

    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;     

    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any 
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;     

    /**
     *  If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back 
     *  as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
     *  is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_ssl = true;      

    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = false; 

    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;       

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';     
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) { 
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        } 

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) { 
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024); 
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024); 
            }
        } 

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return IpnListener::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return IpnListener::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful. 
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and 
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */    
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) { 
            // use raw POST data 
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else { 
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data); 
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST. 
     */    
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And this is my handler script:

```
<?php
/*
ipn.php - example code used for the tutorial:

PayPal IPN with PHP
How To Implement an Instant Payment Notification listener script in PHP
http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html

(c) 2011 - Micah Carrick
*/

// tell PHP to log errors to ipn_errors.log in this directory
ini_set('log_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__).'/ipn_errors.log');

// intantiate the IPN listener
include('ipnlistener.php');
$listener = new IpnListener();

// tell the IPN listener to use the PayPal test sandbox
$listener->use_sandbox = true;

// try to process the IPN POST
try {
    $listener->requirePostMethod();
    $verified = $listener->processIpn();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    exit(0);
}

if ($verified) {

    $errmsg = '';   // stores errors from fraud checks

    // 1. Make sure the payment status is "Completed" 
    if ($_POST['payment_status'] != 'Completed') { 
        // simply ignore any IPN that is not completed
        exit(0); 
    }

    // 2. Make sure seller email matches your primary account email.
    if ($_POST['receiver_email'] != 'mail@example.com') {
        $errmsg .= "'receiver_email' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['receiver_email']."\n";
    }

    // 3. Make sure the amount(s) paid match
        //if ($_POST['mc_gross'] != '9.99') {
            //$errmsg .= "'mc_gross' does not match: ";
            //$errmsg .= $_POST['mc_gross']."\n";
        //}

    // 4. Make sure the currency code matches
    if ($_POST['mc_currency'] != 'USD') {
        $errmsg .= "'mc_currency' does not match: ";
        $errmsg .= $_POST['mc_currency']."\n";
    }

    // 5. Ensure the transaction is not a duplicate.
    mysql_connect('dfdesignzstudiocom.ipagemysql.com','root2121','******') or exit(0);
    mysql_select_db('paypal') or exit(0);


    if (!empty($errmsg)) {

        // manually investigate errors from the fraud checking
        $body = "IPN failed fraud checks: \n$errmsg\n\n";
        $body .= $listener->getTextReport();
        mail('myemail@example.com', 'IPN Fraud Warning', $body);

    } else {
        // add this order to a table of completed orders
        $payer_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['payer_email']);
        $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first_name']);
        $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
        $contact_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contact_phone']);
        $item_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
        $quantity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['quantity']);
        $mc_fee = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_fee']);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (payer_email, first_name, last_name, contact_phone, item_name, quantity, mc_fee) VALUES 
                ('$payer_email', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$contact_phone', '$item_name', '$quantity', '$mc_fee')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
            error_log(mysql_error());
            exit(0);
        }
        // send seller an email with buyer information
        $to = filter_var('myemail@example.com', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $subject = "New Class Registration";
        $message = "Registration Information: \n$first_name $last_name\n$payer_email\nItem Name: $item_name \nQuantity: $quantity\nTotal paid: $mc_fee";
        mail($to, $subject, $message);



$command="mysqldump --xml --host=dfdesignzstudiocom.ipagemysql.com --user=root2121 --password=****** paypal > database.xml";
system($command);

    }
} else {
    // manually investigate the invalid IPN
    mail('myemail@example.com', 'Invalid IPN', $listener->getTextReport());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in your PayPal account > IPN History and viewed the HTML error code by clicking on the Message ID of the transaction in question?

Comment: I have done this already for my situation and no luck.  HTTP Response code is 200, which means successful!  No errors indicated at all here... WTF?  I have resent the Same Notification about 10 times, all with the same Response code: 200, but it never even touches my database...  How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

set $listener->use_sandbox to false

```
 $listener->use_sandbox = false;
```

Comment: Just implemented IPN myself, and did the same thing: Forget to switch the handler to the live PayPal. Just when you think you've checked everything, it is the simple things that trip you up! Fortunately, I had built the functionality into my management page to be able to create the backend record and client notification using the details from the PayPal transaction.