# paypal IPN simulator always giving INVALID response when live,

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, verification

I'm using this: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
and during sandbox testing everything was working fine.

My code is pretty much the same as the one in this question: [Paypal IPN Valid in sandbox INVALID when live](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207281/paypal-ipn-valid-in-sandbox-invalid-when-live)

However, now that I've gone live, every time I do a paypal IPN simulation, it's always "INVALID".

Is it because I'm live? Are simulations only VERIFIED while we're still testing in the sandbox?

Answer (score 5):

If you are trying to use the simulator while posting to the live paypal IPN address, then it will return an INVALID response.  You have to post to the sandbox address in order for the IPN simulator to return a VERIFIED response.

If using the simulator with a live post address, it will return an HTTP code of 200, but the response will always be INVALID.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having this same problem as well. Did you change both of the $listener->use_sandbox variables to false (in ipn.php and ipnlistener.php)? Have you enabled IPN notifications in your PayPal account? If you  have not done the latter, you can do so with the following: Profile-->Settings-->My selling tools-->Instant payment notifications-->Update.

What does the 'Message ID' associated with that particular IPN notification say? (you can access this in your IPN history)

Mine has the following (relevant information):

Date/time created: 29/04/2013 16:21 AEST

Latest delivery attempt date/time: 11/05/1985 02:23 AEST

HTTP response code: 200

Delivery status: Sent

IPN type: Other transaction made

I'm wondering why the latest delivery attempt date/time is listed as being in 1985... Perhaps you have something similar for yours? Sorry I have not solved your problem for you, but perhaps I have given you some additional things to look into? And, I'm sure the others that answer will probably want to know these things as well. :-)

PS: you might consider checking your server access logs. When I checked mine, I discovered that the IPNs from the Sandbox were being posted successfully; however, the live ones weren't.

PPS: I fixed my issue by making sure the IP addresses listed here (for use by PayPal) were able to post to my website: [explanation](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14/kw/IPN%20not%20working) and [addresses](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/92)